# CVE-2011-4885 security issue and PHP 5.2

Tags: php, security

We still use PHP 5.2.17 (from dotdeb) in production environment, but I don't find any release which correct the CVE-2011-4885 security issue. Even in PHP SVN 5.2 branch I don't find any commit for 6 months.

How can I handle this? Using PHP 5.3 is the goal, but we still need more time to test and correct old code.

Comment: Does your version of PHP have the Suhosin patch compiled in?

Comment: In 5.3.9 [this was fixed](http://www.php.net/archive/2012.php#id2012-01-10-1) by adding [`max_input_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) directive to php.ini. I found [this patch](https://github.com/laruence/laruence.github.com/blob/master/php-5.2-max-input-vars/php-5.2.17-max-input-vars.patch) which seems to be a fix for 5.2.17 providing the same functionality.

Comment: @DaveRandom: If its a backport of the 5.3.9 code, you probably don't want to use it, since 5.3.10 fixes the remote code execution hole it introduced. Replacing hashdos with potential remote root is probably not advisable :P

Comment: There was a remotely exploitable bug with the 5.3.9 implementation of max_input_vars, which is why they recently released 5.3.10.  Suhosin should actually help with this particular situation - check out settings like `suhosin.request.max_vars = 1000`.

Comment: Building on the suggestion by @DaveRandom, if you use the backported max_input_vars patch, along with [the 5.3.9 -> 5.3.10 fix](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/php_variables.c?r1=323007&r2=321827), you should be good to go. Or just use Suhosin :)

Comment: @Leigh My C-fu is nowhere near good enough to pass an informed comment on this situation. I'm guessing this is likely to be an issue though, since the patch was authored in late Dec and 5.3.10 is only 4 days old...

Comment: Yes, Suhosin is enabled. How to use it? Can I actually protect my old 5.2.17 by using suhosin.request.max_vars = 1000 ?

Comment: @CédricGirard: Make it lower, suhosin defaults to 200 (in the latest versions - not sure about yours). The exploit relies on passing a large number of request variables (>100000). Most sites can set the value even lower. Simply put the configuration values in your `php.ini`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building the comments of myself and others into a solid answer.

If your version of PHP has the Suhosin patch installed (Check your `phpinfo()`) then you can use the `suhosin.request.max_vars` configuration value. This defaults to 200 so your install will be pretty safe by default.

If not DaveRandom has suggested a [5.2.17 backport of the max_input_vars patch](https://github.com/laruence/laruence.github.com/blob/master/php-5.2-max-input-vars/php-5.2.17-max-input-vars.patch). However this patch may still be vulnerable to the exploit fixed in PHP 5.3.10

You can see what was [changed in 5.3.10](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/php_variables.c?r1=323007&r2=321827) to fix this exploit, but the code is not directly applicable to 5.2.17.

Use at your own risk, but upgrade to the latest version of PHP as soon as you can.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP 5.2 branch is no longer supported by PHP. I'm pretty sure that means they're not even doing bug fixes or security patches. You're strongly recommended to upgrade to the 5.3 branch (although I'm aware that's not always easy).